# Undefined reference to "readimagefile" to add image to window while using WinBGI graphics library on dev C++

Tags: c++, image, dev-c++, bgi, winbgi

I have a hangman game project using graphics. And, I am trying to add image to the windows, but I get the error of

> Untitled1.cpp:(.text+0x72): undefined reference to `readimagefile'

```
#include <iostream>
#include<graphics.h>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

// Loading Game

int main()

{
    
    initwindow(600,600, "Hello");
    readimagefile("hangmanLogo.png", 0,0,100,42);

    settextstyle(10, 0, 2);
    setbkcolor(7);
    settextstyle(10, 0, 7);
    outtextxy(170,200, "H_ngm_n");  
    rectangle(260,298,340,308);
    setcolor(YELLOW);

    for(int i=0;i<=76;i++)

    {
        line(262+i,300,262+i,306);
        delay(70);
    }
    
    cleardevice();

return 0;
}
```

The code runs fine without the `readimagefile` function. But when I use this, I get this error.
I've included the header file of `graphics.h`. I've also linked the following. `-lbgi -lgdi32 -lcomdlg32 -luuid -loleaut32 -lole32`.

Comment: Warning: BGI is very old technology for DOS-based computers. It is literally a tool from the 1980s. It hasn't been used for much professionally since being rendered obsolete by Windows in the 1990s. WinBGI was written to port it to Windows XP, so 20 year-old technology again. If you have a modern computer odds are good that you can do EVERYTHING right and it still won't work simply because your OS and graphics card are too new.

Comment: But what you've probably run into is WinBGI was compiled for GCC 3.3. If your tools are anywhere near up to date you're using at least GCC 9.3 and mainline GCC is version 13.2. A lot has changed and the WinBGI binaries are unlikely to still be compatible. If you have to use WinBGI, I recommend making a Windows XP virtual machine and install GCC 3.3, if you can still find it. If you can update to a more modern distribution of BGI, I suggest you use: https://sdl-bgi.sourceforge.io/.

Comment: If you can upgrade to modern graphics programming, either [SDL](https://www.libsdl.org/) or [SFML](https://www.sfml-dev.org/) should be suitable. Before doing any updating, make certain whoever has assigned the use of this dinosaur to you is OK with the change and can compile and run the result. Nothing worse than handing in an assignment that is correct and still failing because the marker's tools are hopelessly obsolete.

Comment: Okay Thank you. I will switch to SDL.

Comment: *"The code runs fine without the **readimagefile** function."* -- This is an excellent step towards a truly minimal [mre]. The next step is (to try) to run the code with **only** the `readimagefile` function, something like `#include<graphics.h> int main() { readimagefile("hangmanLogo.png", 0,0,100,42); }`. I suspect this is enough to reproduce the error, in which case the question needs no more code than this.

Comment: *"Please suggest me the solutions as soon as possible as my project deadline is getting near."* -- Your emergency is not our emergency. See [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)